# Build docker image based on an image in private ECR repo

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr

This is what I'm trying to do. I have a docker image that is in a private ECR repo. This docker image is built off a base docker image that is also in a different private ECR repo. I have been able to build this docker image off the base image locally, but when executing the build of this docker image in the pipeline, I am getting the following error:

```
+ docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.793MB
Step 1/8 : FROM base/docker-image:latest
pull access denied for base/docker-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Since both of the docker images I have are stored in separate, private ECR repos I'm not sure if I need to integrate a secret within my EKS cluster in order for this pipeline to be able to pull from the base docker image repo. I have integrated a secret with the docker image that allows that to be pulled. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to login into ECR for fetching the image from the private repo. Try adding the login command before the docker build command -

```
eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region <aws_region>)
```

You will also need to define the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY variables to allow permission to login into ecr and also install awscli in the pipeline if you haven't previously.